# Entity Framework Select Sub Class at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a structure as follow

```
public class Mammal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string PrintName()
        {
            return "The name is " + Name;
        }
    }

    public class Dog : Mammal
    {
        public string Breed { get; set; }

        public new string PrintName()
        {
            return "The name is " + Name + " and i go woof woof";
        }
    }
```

At runtime based on a property i am selecting data from entity framework and want to return the correct child type based on a variable.

How can i specify which subclass to use in my entity framework select query?

Comment: can you share a sample code how are you selecting that data?

Comment: context.Animals.Select(x => new Mammal { Name = x.Name}); But I want the new Mammal to be determined at runtime ideally